# How do I restore accidentally deleted unstaged changes from a commit amendment?

Tags: git, github

I wanted to change my last commit message so I followed this guide to amend the commit: https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-commit-message.

Unfortunately, somewhere in the process, I appear to have lost my unstaged changes.

Here's what I did:

- `git commit --amend`
- Amend the commit message at the top
- `git push`
- This didn't work so I did `git push --force` as suggested by the guide as I had already pushed the last change

Somewhere between `git commit --amend` and `git push --force` I have lost all my unstaged changes. How do I get them back?

---

## Fixed!

I'd changed my git aliases which caused me to accidentally stash all my changes when I tried to get my git status to see what had happened.

Comment: I guess you meant you lost your unstaged *changes*, since unstaged commits would make no sense. And nothing in what you described is supposed to get rid of unstaged changes. Did you stash/reset/checkout at any point in-between? Check your `history`.

Comment: Thanks @RomainValeri. Helped me get to the bottom of things.

Comment: Oh so it *was* `stash`, yeah I guess this was the most probable cause. Glad you found it.